# How to debug Cython in an IDE

Tags: python, c++, debugging, cython

I am trying to debug Cython code that wraps a c++ class, and the error I am hunting is somewhere in the C++ code.

It would be awfully convenient if I could somehow debug as if it were written in one language, i.e. if there's an error in the C++ part, it would show me the source code line there, and if the error is in the Python part it would do the same.

Right now I always have to try and replicate the Python code using the class in C++, and right now I have an error that only occurs when running through Python ... I hope somebody can help me out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a while for me and I forgot how I exactly did it, but when I was writing my own C/C++ library and interfaced it with swig into python, I was able to debug the C code with [DDD](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/). It was important to compile with debug options. It wasn't great, but it worked for me. I think you had to run `ddd python` and within the python terminal run my faulty C code. You would have to make sure all linked libraries including yours is loaded with the source code so that you could set breakpoints.

Comment: I'll give this a try, thanks! This DDD seems less appealing than say doing the same in pycharm, but one shouldn't be too picky :)

Comment: No, DDD is by far not user friendly and has many downsides, but it's the default frontend for the GNU debugger gdb so that compatibility is at least ensured. Good luck.