# How to debug Cython code in a modern IDE like VSCode?

Tags: cython, vscode-debugger, pdb

I'd like to know how people debug their Cython code, do they just use terminal debugging as suggested in the [Doc](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/debugging.html)?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906830/how-to-debug-cython-in-an-ide) suggests it is possible with [DDD](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/), not to knock DDD, but I don't want to change my whole workflow for debugging Cython code.

Surely, this must be possible in VSCode?

Comment: [this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2900) shows how to attach GDB to PyDB debugger. I guess you need to do the same with the cython extension of GDB detailed in the Cython docs.

Comment: Oh thanks I didn’t see that when searching. Will try it out and report back.

Comment: Please do! I'm extremely interested. So far I've been forced to debug the naive way: print statements, logs and error messages.